# Start-Process using EncodedCommand outputs to Standard Error

Tags: powershell

The following script demonstrates an issue I'm experiencing after moving from PowerShell v4 to v5.1. I make extensive use of Start-Process redirecting StandardError to a file, if this file contains data after execution I can read the file to see what the issue was.

However, with v5.1 when the launched PowerShell process starts, it makes use of progress output which is on the error stream, so this is redirected to the error file. In previous versions of PowerShell this did not happen, if I use **Command** rather than **EncodedCommand** it works as expected.

I believe this is a bug but it would be useful if someone could confirm or suggest a workaround?

The output to the script below is as follows:

### PowerShell v4

> No Errors
> hello world!

### PowerShell v5.1

> WARNING:
>
> SourceId Record
>
> ---
>
> ```
>    1 parent = -1 id = 0 act = Preparing modules for first use. stat =   cur =  pct = -1 sec = -1 type = Completed
> ```
>
> hello world!
>
> hello world!

### Demo Script

**Note**: this will create 2 temporary files, which are both deleted at the end.

```
$outfile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
$errorfile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()

$command = "write-host 'hello world!'"
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command))
$argumentList = @(
    "-NoLogo",
    "-NonInteractive",
    "-NoProfile",
    "-EncodedCommand",
    $encodedCommand
)

Start-Process powershell `
    -argumentlist $argumentList `
    -PassThru `
    -wait `
    -RedirectStandardOut $outfile  `
    -NoNewWindow `
    -RedirectStandardError $errorfile | Out-Null

if ((Get-Item $errorfile).length -gt 0)
{
    Import-Clixml $errorfile | Out-String | Write-Warning 
}
else 
{
    Write-Host "No Errors"
}

Get-Content $outfile
$outfile, $errorfile | Remove-item
```

Comment: I strongly [recommend reading this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1).  Escaping newlines with a backtick is a recipe for disaster.  You also don't need to use `Start-Process` at all in your example.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I'm aware that the script above could be written differently, but it is contrived to show a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I agreed, it *should* be plain text, but it isn't, maybe another bug introduced in v5.1 if this detail detracts from the question, I'll update it to be Get-Content. Whether I use Get-Content or Import-CliXml the fact remains the file size is greater than zero - which is the real problem,

Comment: No I don't, nor do I get an issue if I use *command* rather than *encodedcommand* but for various other reasons I'm stuck with encodedcommand. Do you have a v5.1 that you could test this on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177201/discussion-between-david-martin-and-theincorrigible1).

Comment: So I was able to replicate on Win7, v5.1 and I have a theory.  All streams besides `output` (1) are being redirected as error.  The text you're getting is powershell starting up and auto-loading modules.  It's a `InformationRecord` object

Comment: Agreed, I alluded to that in my question "it makes use of progress output which is on the error stream".

This was the case in v4 if there were modules being loaded, but these were visible if a new powershell window was launched. In my case I don't see the progress being displayed for a normal window. So I guess the question is how to suppress the progress?

Comment: It's actually put out on the information stream (6), not error (2).  This was a new addition in v5 and may be the cause of your bug.

Comment: Good observation, but I don't think we have control over that with start-process? It's also interesting to note that this only happens with EncodedCommand not command.

Comment: I cannot provide any more information at this point, but good luck.

Comment: Just to add: from what I was checking it's stream 4, not 6 as when I set `$WarningPreference = "SilentlyContinue"` nothing was displayed.

Comment: @robdy That's because he's piping the object to `Write-Warning`.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I missed that part!